# Reference Error: function is not defined (javascript/html)

Tags: javascript, html

**Edit: Ok, here's an update, I don't what I just did but for some reason it now works on my website. Right now my website has a total of 5 html files, all sharing the same javascript file. Can anyone explain why some pages include the script and some don't? I don't know what the exact problem is but it appears that in some cases, the javascript code will only work on 2 of the 5 pages.**

I have been trying to find a solution to this problem to the point where I nearly changed the structure of my javascript code and now I'm frustrated. I have tried so many methods to best of my knowledge and it just won't budge. Maybe I missed something but I'm sure that the syntax is correct, but it's still showing this error when I execute the script on the website.

Here's are pieces of the code, the button is on the bottom of the HTML code.

```js
function validate() {
  var firstName = document.getElementById("fname").value;

  if (firstName.length === 0) {
    alert("You must fill out this field: First Name");
    throw new Error("You must fill out this field: First Name");
  } else if (!firstName.match(/\s*[A-Za-z]+[-]*[A-Za-z]*/)) {
    alert("Invalid format");
    throw new Error("Invalid format");
  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Rent Online</title>
  <style>
    form {
      width: auto;
    }
    label {
      float: left;
      width: 200px;
    }
    input[type=text] {
      float: left;
      width: 250px;
    }
    input[type=password] {
      float: left;
      width: 250px;
    }
    .clear {
      clear: both;
      height: 0;
      line-height: 0;
    }
    .floatright {
      float: right;
    }
  </style>
  <script type="javascript/text" src="Script.js"></script>             <!-- Script file -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="Body">
    <div class="TopHalf">
      <img src="images/WebLogo.jpg" style="width: 200px; height: 150px; 
      border-bottom-right-radius: 38px; box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 15px #0a0a0a;">

      <p>User Registration</p>
    </div>
    <div class="BottomHalf">
      <div class="NavBar">
        <a href="Home.html">Home</a>
        <a href="Owners.html">Owners</a>
        <a href="Tenants.html">Tenants</a>
        <a href="Rent.html">Rent</a>
        <a href="UserReg.html">User Registration</a>
      </div>
      <div class="info" style="background: url(images/Sunny.jpg); background-size: cover;">
        <div style="background: rgba(163, 209, 255, .7);">
          <form id="userform">
            <label for="fname">1. First Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="fname">
            <br>
            <br>
            <label for="lname">2. Last Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="lname">
            <br>
            <br>3. Are you an Owner or a Tenant?
            <br>
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="person" value="owner">Owner
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="person" value="tenant">Tenant
            <br>
            <br>
            <label for="pnum">4. Phone Number:</label>
            <input type="text" id="pnum">
            <br>
            <br>
            <label for="email">5. Email:</label>
            <input type="text" id="email">
            <br>
            <br>
            <label for="nickname">6. Login ID:</label>
            <input type="text" id="nickname">
            <br>
            <br>
            <label for="pass">7. Password:</label>
            <input type="password" id="pass">
            <br>
            <br>
            <label for="password">8. Confirm Password:</label>
            <input type="password" id="conpass">
            <br>
            <br>
          </form>
          <button onclick="validate()">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce: http://jsbin.com/kazodukeco/1/ (and you provided a live example in the question which doesn't reproduce the problem either!)

Comment: Ctrl+F5 or clear browsers cache? just in case your browser uses a cached version of something

Comment: This doesn't make any sense, why does this code work in JSbin but not my own webpage? Maybe there's something in my html code that's preventing my javascript from working, I'll edit the sample to give you my full code.

Comment: Could you provide links for pages in which it works and pages in which it doesn't?

Comment: In your original post, you were using .reset() on an input element, this function threw the error `TypeError: document.getElementById(...).reset is not a function`, so if I added some numbers in the firstName field I did get your error :) Btw, returning true/false from the validate function and adding to the form `onsubmit="return validate();"` you could stop the submission in case a user presses enter in the textfields :)

Comment: For form validation you need to use a different approach. check this link.http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp

Comment: @ Alfonso: Sorry, it's not uploaded anywhere for you to see, it's only on my drive. I wanted to send a picture but apparently I need up to 10 rep points to do that. :(

@ Icepickle: Yes I fixed it and it's working properly, it's just that in firebug, for some reason, the code doesn't show in three particular pages even though the link in all html pages are the same syntax connecting to the same .js file. Thanks for the tip btw :).

Comment: @Alak, thanks, that will be good to know, I only did it this way because it's for an assignment.